# Google Maps geocoder does not find places that are not exact addresses, unlike the Google Maps website

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use the Google Maps geocoding service. I copied the code and it seems to find addresses fine (for example "13 Marine Terrace Aberystwyth") but not other places like "Rummers Wine Bar, Aberystwyth" even though the actual Google Maps website has no problem with them at all.

This is my code, slightly modified to be for the Aberystwyth area but otherwise copied form https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript"


/*you can use https if you want it secure!!!    set java scrip sensor to true and read from gps!*/


      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXo-tdDimvjIs&sensor=false&region=GB">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

var geocoder;
  var map;
  function initialize() {
     geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.4156, -4.0829);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 14,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  }

   function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
         map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             map: map,
             position: results[0].geometry.location

         });

      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
            function code ()
                           {document.write(results[0].geometry.location);}
    });
  }
      </script>
    </head>

<body onload="initialize()">
 <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 320px; height: 480px;"></div>
  <div>
   <input id="address" type="textbox" value="aberystwyth">
   <input type="button" value="Encode" onclick="codeAddress()">
  </div>
      </script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
    code();
   </script>
 </body>
```

This is a link to it: http://users.aber.ac.uk/avh9/thesite/geocodeaber.html

Can anyone tell me why and how to fix it? or any alternative for geocoding....

Comment: I don't think their public geocoding api handles business names or landmark names, but just postal addresses.

Answer (score 6):

There's a library called [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) within Google Maps API. You can use its <strike>`search()`</strike> `nearbySearch()` or `textSearch()` methods to search for POIs and landmarks.